# Accessing context from a custom View

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When configuring the views of a calendar, [view specific options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options) can be specified. But the documentation about [custom views](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) says nothing on how to retrieve these options.

Is there any way to get these options here and so to make the custom view to behave function of them ?

Is there even a way to access the [view object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object) from a custom view callback ? (maybe the options are available on it)

Comment: That documentation says `Props
Both the config and component techniques receive “props”, an object with information about the current view. You’ll need to look at the FullCalendar v5 source code to see exactly what’s in props.`. does that not answer your question?

Comment: Not really, [there are](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/packages/common/src/View.ts#L9-L20) some props indeed but not one about the view itself, nor the specific-view options.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used, but I think that should be part of the core behavior, is to use the undocumented [`viewPropsTransformers`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/f55ba69a8247dda0cc6bb0c4aefceed21bf17eb9/packages/common/src/CalendarContent.tsx#L209) option when creating a custom view through a call to `createPlugin` :

```js
class MorePropsToView {
  transform(viewProps, calendarProps) {
    return {
      ...viewProps,
      options: calendarProps.viewSpec.optionOverrides,
      calendar: calendarProps.calendarApi,
    }
  }
}

export const myPlugin = createPlugin({
  views: {
    custom: CustomView,
  },
  viewPropsTransformers: MorePropsToView,
})
```

So the two extra props are available in the custom view :

```js
const CustomView = function CustomView({
  eventStore,
  dateProfile,
  options,
  calendar,
}) {
  console.log(options, calendar)
}
```

Comment: I understand i'm kinda leaching knowledge that you get from digging trough their codebase, i'm kinda unfamiliar with react altough i tried a fair bit.
Do you have any other tips for dealing with this custom views? For example, how do I specify that a particular node can contain events and the element i add as event is indeed an event? do they do that with attributes like for data-date?
For the moment i accomplished it by manually adding mouse event listeners to them to simulate the dateclick and selection events.